# Allow IAM user to view already created EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I know this may look Naive but i am new to AWS,

I have an already launched EC2 instance and I created an IAM user, i want this user to view this instance, but when he open EC2 on his account it tells him his current instance is zero, how can i allow him to view it and use CloudWatch on it?

Comment: Is he viewing EC2 instances in the correct region? Does his IAM policy allow ec2 permissions (ec2:Describe*). Are there any error messages in the AWS console when viewing EC2?

Comment: My mistake was I was in the wrong region :/